# Why does my app crashes on Google Play when opened for the first time?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-app-bundle

I am recently facing this issue, the previous bundle uploaded on google play store works fine but recently the uploaded bundle crashes on the first run and works fine on the second run. As of previous bundles, they are crashing too. I am unable to test for this issue locally as the app only crashes once uploaded on google play.

I connected my device to adb and got this error stack

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver io.branch.referral.InstallListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.branch.referral.InstallListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.et.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.fr.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.xhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.et.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.fr.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.xhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
02-06 14:55:02.493  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3581)
02-06 14:55:02.493  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
02-06 14:55:02.493  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1803)
02-06 14:55:02.493  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
02-06 14:55:02.493  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
02-06 14:55:02.493  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7091)
02-06 14:55:02.493  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-06 14:55:02.493  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
02-06 14:55:02.493  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
02-06 14:55:02.493  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.branch.referral.InstallListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.et.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.fr.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.xhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.et.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.fr.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.xhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
02-06 14:55:02.493  7189  7263 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver(AppComponentFactory.java:84)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver(Unknown Source:0)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3574)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: ... 8 more
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:766)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:849)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1090)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6141)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1792)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: ... 6 more
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.et.apk
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:766)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:849)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1090)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6141)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1792)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: ... 6 more
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.fr.apk
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:766)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:849)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1090)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6141)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1792)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: ... 6 more
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.packagename..-XIjBO38t41Xg612j8yF42g==/split_config.xhdpi.apk
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:766)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:849)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1090)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6141)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1792)
02-06 14:55:02.494  7189  7189 E AndroidRuntime: ... 6 more















Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.appsflyer.FirebaseInstanceIdListener>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService;
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at com.appsflyer.internal.k$d com.appsflyer.internal.k.ˏ(android.content.Context) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.ॱ(android.content.Context, java.util.Map) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.util.Map com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.ˏ(com.appsflyer.internal.j) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.ॱ(com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore, com.appsflyer.internal.j) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore$a.run() (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() (Executors.java:459)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:266)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run() (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AFExecutor$3$2.run() (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.packagename..-ecUbKqNnZ_YIbwaC012sfw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.packagename..-ecUbKqNnZ_YIbwaC012sfw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.packagename..-ecUbKqNnZ_YIbwaC012sfw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at com.appsflyer.internal.k$d com.appsflyer.internal.k.ˏ(android.content.Context) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.ॱ(android.content.Context, java.util.Map) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.util.Map com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.ˏ(com.appsflyer.internal.j) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.ॱ(com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore, com.appsflyer.internal.j) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore$a.run() (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() (Executors.java:459)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:266)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run() (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AFExecutor$3$2.run() (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
02-06 14:53:35.619  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.appsflyer.FirebaseInstanceIdListener>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService;
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at com.appsflyer.internal.k$d com.appsflyer.internal.k.ˏ(android.content.Context) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.ॱ(android.content.Context, java.util.Map) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.util.Map com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.ˏ(com.appsflyer.internal.j) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.ॱ(com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore, com.appsflyer.internal.j) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore$a.run() (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() (Executors.java:459)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:266)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run() (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AFExecutor$3$2.run() (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.packagename..-ecUbKqNnZ_YIbwaC012sfw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.packagename..-ecUbKqNnZ_YIbwaC012sfw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.packagename..-ecUbKqNnZ_YIbwaC012sfw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at com.appsflyer.internal.k$d com.appsflyer.internal.k.ˏ(android.content.Context) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.ॱ(android.content.Context, java.util.Map) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.util.Map com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.ˏ(com.appsflyer.internal.j) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.ॱ(com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore, com.appsflyer.internal.j) (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore$a.run() (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() (Executors.java:459)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:266)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run() (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
02-06 14:53:35.620  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void com.appsflyer.AFExecutor$3$2.run() (:-1)
02-06 14:53:35.621  5789  6022 I l.fresh.mailbo:   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
```

I have already included `com.android.Installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1` in app/build.gradle.

Comment: Did you introduce AppsFlyer recently? Do you use code obfuscation?

Comment: @Pierre no we already had AppsFlyer in our app, and there is no code obfuscation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this tag from your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

for more details check https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking-attribution/issues/539

Comment: Hey, Thanks it helped a lot.